# 3-dimensional dataset using Python

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I'm trying to write this parameter's dataset in Python. I used `xarray`, but I couldn't get right codes... How can i write this dataset in Python?

I write sets and the dataset of a parameter below.

```
Sets
i "products" /i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10/
j "processing units" /j1, j2,  j3/
s "production sites" /s1, s2, s3/;

Table v(i,j,s)
          s1       s2       s3      
i1.j1     5                 
i2.j1     5        
i3.j1     5        
i4.j1     5        
i5.j2              6
i6.j2              6
i7.j2              6
i8.j2              6
i9.j3                        4
i10.j3                       4
;
```

How can i write this dataset in Python?

Comment: You need to provide much more detail on what these data actually represent, what you plan on doing with them and what the output needs to look like.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the example that you gave is not easy to follow however I tried to write something that would help.
You can use np.meshgrid:

```
i = ["i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", "i8", "i9", "i10"]
j = ["j1", "j2",  "j3"]
s = ["s1", "s2", "s3"]
grid3d_i, grid3d_j, grid3d_s = np.meshgrid(i, j, s, indexing='ij')
# then you can print one print one point in 3d data like this:
grid3d_i[0][0][0], grid3d_j[0][0][0], grid3d_s[0][0][0]
```